# javascript style - should I define variables/classes?

Tags: javascript

Many functions in my code use this structure:

```
options = {"param1": "yes", "param2" : "no"}
```

In JS I do not have to "define" this structure since it is a dynamic language.

But when I know the structure has a fixed set of fields, is it a best practice to declare it in some centralized way, just for clearness? The same goes for usage in local data members in a class. Is it a best practice to init all of them in a ctor or some other centralized way (for clearness)?

I know I could do that in comment but coming from a static language I want to know what is the javascript style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm hoping you normally have a `var` on the front of that. :-) Without one, you're falling prey to [*The Horror Of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).)

There's no real convention other than being clear. For **me**, "being clear" means a couple of things:

1. Put all `var` statements at the beginning of the scope, because [that's where they really are anyway](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html).
2. If something has a significant structure that won't be changing much, assign it with an object literal (as you have) as early as reasonable.

...but "being clear" means different things to different people.

> The same goes for usage in local data members in a class. Is it a best practice to init all of them in a ctor or some other centralized way (for clearness)?

Yes, initialize all instance-specific properties in the constructor. Properties that the object may not need its own copy of can reside on the prototype:

```
function Foo(bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
    this.baz = [];
}
Foo.prototype.datum = 42;
```

There, an object created via `new Foo("x")` will get its *own* property `bar` with the value `"x"`, it's *own* property `baz` with the value `[]`, and an inherited property `datum` with the value `42`. Putting those initializations in the constructor and on the prototype right next to it aid clarity.

Answer (score 1):

generally you can do a lot more if you go with a function definition, take the rectangle example.

```
function Rectangle(width, height){
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
};

Rectangle.prototype.width = 0;
Rectangle.prototype.height = 0;
Rectangle.prototype.getArea = function(){
  return this.height * this.width;
}

var rect = new Rectangle(100, 50);

console.log(rect.width);
console.log(rect.height);
console.log(rect.getArea());
```

With this approach, some IDEs support autocomplete and you can manipulate intrinsic object methods, such as .toString, etc.  It's best practice to do so if you feel your needs might expand, not too sure about performance benchmarks yet depending on how far you want to take "best practice".

Answer (score 1):

If you're passing `options` in as a parameter to a function call, the typical way to deal with this is to make your function have a default set of values for all parameters where possible, then pass an object literal into the function where you desire to specify options.

For example, if `myFunction` has options `color`, `size` and `material`, assign as many default values as makes sense (e.g. default `color` is `red`, default `size` is `large` and default `material` is `cotton`). Then when you call `myFunction()` the defaults apply unless you call it like this:

```
myFunction({color:'blue', material:'suede'});
```

Here the only default value retained would be size.

This is how jQuery and many other libraries tend to do options.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are some ways to define classes.

```
// serves as a constructor
function MyClass(name, id) {
    // init members.
    // this.members are public members
    this.Name = name;
    this.Id = id;

    // this is a private member available only in constructor
    var something = 0;
    this.DoSomething = function () {
        // your method
        // here you also can use something here as you have access.
    }
}

MyClass.prototype = {
    // This also another way to define your methods
    "SomeMethod": function (input) {
        // Do something
        // you don't have access to private members in constructor.
    }
}
```

Further if you want some more OOP features

```
function AnotherClass (input) {
    // private field
    var someNumber = 0;
    // get accessor
    this.getSomeNumber = function() {
        return someNumber;
    }
    this.setSomeNumber = function(value) {
        if (typeof value != "number" || value != value)
            throw new Error("Your value must be a number");
        someNumber = value;
    }
}
```

If you want some static methods then here are they

```
var MyThirdClass = (function() {
    var instanceCount = 0;
    function _Constructor() {
        this.Name = "";
        instanceCount++;
    }
    _Constructor.getInstanceCount = function() {
        return instanceCount;
    }
    return _Constructor;
})();
```

And finally you can use them as follows

```
var myClass = new MyClass("Foo", 1);
myClass.Name = "Bar";
myClass.DoSomething();

var thirdClass = new MyThirdClass();
var thirdClassAnotherInstance = new MyThirdClass();
alert(MyThirdClass.getInstanceCount());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would `recommend` you to `create a separate generic .js` file that is `imported in all pages`, centralizing all `default options`. Also it's awesome because of `reusability` (you won't need to reconfigure the same things all time you need it).

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill for your situation, but if you wanted you could create a constructor function with getters and setters for specific private variables.  This particular one also checks that the set value is a number before setting.

```
var Options = function(p1, p2){
    var _param1, _param2;

    this.get_param1 = function(){
        return _param1;
    };
    this.get_param2 = function(){
        return _param2;
    };

    this.set_param1 = function(v){
        if (typeof(v) === 'number') {
            _param1 = v;
            return _param1;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
    this.set_param2 = function(v){
        if (typeof(v) === 'number') {
            _param2 = v;
            return _param2;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };

    this.set_param1(p1);
    this.set_param2(p2);

    return this;
};
```

Usage would be like:

```
var options = new Options(1, 2);
options._param1; // => undefined
options.get_param1(); // => 1
options.get_param2(); // => 2
options.set_param1(3);
options.get_param1(); // => 3
options.set_param1('fail');
options.get_param1(); // => 3
```

It's a very rigid implementation but might be what you're looking for.